# Video-to-video with custom model to achieve a kind of « mise en abîme »

Tags: stable-diffusion

I’m new to generative AI but want to learn.  I have a good experience in graphic techniques and softwares - especially 3D (Blender) and After Effects.
I have also coding skills; so I guess I could have a try.

What I want to do is to use video-to-video with a custom model to make a kind of « mise en abîme » :

**For example, let’s say I have an input video of a cat walking.
I want to train an AI model with only pictures of cats.
Then generate a new video, from my walking cat video, using my cats model.**

This should look as my input video, but with a kind of glitchy/dreamy look.
Do you see the idea?

I’ve read a bit on stable diffusion / ComfyUI / Kohya-SS; but all of this is still a bit blurry to me.

Could you give me some hints about how to do this?  What would be the process, steps, difficulties and softwares to use ?  Maybe similar references?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems a very expensive way to generate such an effect: training a model is very energy-intensive, and that's _if_ you have the right hardware (if you don't, it's even more expensive). Have you considered something like an auto-generated collage (performing similarity checks between chunks of a cat-picture corpus and your source video (not in the corpus) to get the pieces) with an [image stitching algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09578)?

Comment: Hi, have you got some examples of the technique you're talking about ?PS I don't want something where the cat changes at each frame, I want a smooth result, more like a dream.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that approach wouldn't be smooth: the _whole thing_ wouldn't change _every_ frame, but different bits would change every few frames. If smoothness is very important, I might suggest 3D modelling? If you can get your cat video from a couple of angles, you could use NeRF, then play around with whatever dream-like effects you desire. (The Wikipedia article for this technique is possibly compromised by ChatGPT garbage, so you'll have to take the old-fashioned follow-the-references approach: [this article was in my internet history](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.04079).)

Comment: Yes but then I would need to animate the whole 3D scene!  I don’t want it to be realistic.  It should look like a dream.  That’s why I thought of IA (the weird « morphing » aspect of it)

Comment: You wouldn't need to animate the whole scene; NeRF would do that for you. You'd only need to synchronise the video feeds with each other. But you might be able to get the morphing aspect by abusing an interframe compression algorithm: look into "remove video i-frames" or something similar. (The general term is "datamoshing".)

Comment: "mise en abîme" is a formal technique of placing a copy of an image within itself. Is it really what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 would you know some examples of that ?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul maybe i'm mistaken on the term. What I want is to "regenerate" a new image based on a limited library of images. (I think :))

Comment: @gordie I couldn't find any of the examples I was thinking of, but [the Wikipedia article has a decent one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DATAMOSH_STREET.webm). Effects will depend on the compression algorithm used (this one was originally published in 2011, so would not have been using webm's VP9), where the i-frames are, etc.. If you don't like the squares, you can process it further.